# How can SubtleCrypto help in the process of sending a password via HTTPS?

Tags: tls, authentication, passwords

I heard from someone that SubtleCrypto should be used in client-server communications to login and register, then he told me it would be useful even if someone took control in the middle of the HTTPS connection. I always thought that once the TLS failed, nothing else could be reliable (at least between 2 peers.)

Since I've never heard of SubtleCrypto nor this case specifically, and the documentation I've found is scarse and not really concrete, could someone explain how this would work? (if it would)

Edit: notice the way he thought of was encoding the password with SubtleCrypto, then send it to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very top of the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) has the following warning:

> **Warning:** This API provides a number of low-level cryptographic primitives. It's very easy to misuse them, and the pitfalls involved can be very subtle.
>
> Even assuming you use the basic cryptographic functions correctly, secure key management and overall security system design are extremely hard to get right, and are generally the domain of specialist security experts.
>
> Errors in security system design and implementation can make the security of the system completely ineffective.
>
> **If you're not sure you know what you are doing, you probably shouldn't be using this API.**

This simply means if someone is able to successfully mount a Man-in-the-Middle attack against you, then just throwing more and more cryptography at the problem with the hope that something will be effective is just the plain wrong way to go.

But to answer the question "How can SubtleCrypto help in the process of sending a password via HTTPS?", the answer is "not really all that much".

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing password authentication without the client actually sending the password over the network is using Secure Remote Password (SRP) as a Password-based Authenticated Key Exchange (PAKE).  For more information on how SRP works, see [the official site](http://srp.stanford.edu/) or [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol).

For authentication between a web browser and a web server, SRP can be implemented using client-side scripting, which is served by the web server and runs in the web browser, as [1Password has done](https://blog.1password.com/1password-is-layerup-ed-with-modern-authentication/) (although I don't believe 1Password's solution uses the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) specifically).

However, there is a caveat.  As has already been pointed out, if an attacker is able breach the server or pull-off a MITM attack, then he may be able to steal the user's password by inserting malicious code in the client-side scripting that runs in the user's web browser.